# Databinding on a property of a UserControl in DetailsView

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

I have developped a usercontrol, but I can't seem to find how to databind on a property of the usercontrol in a detailsview.

The property is defined this way:

```
<Bindable(True, BindingDirection.TwoWay)>
Public Property Value As String
    Get
        Return combobox.SelectedValue
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        combobox.SelectedValue = value
    End Set
End Property
```

My databinding in my details view is done this way:

```
<myctls:DropDown runat="server" 
                 ID="ctlSupplier" 
                 Value='<%#Bind("supplier_id") %>' />
```

Whenever I try to Databind, I get the following exception:

> Databinding methods such as Eval(),
>   XPath(), and Bind() can only be used
>   in the context of a databound control.

Anyone got any ideas of how to make it possible to databind on a property of a usercontrol ?

**Edit 1: Added DetailsViewCode and object datasource **

```
<asp:DetailsView runat="server" ID="dvMain" DataSourceID="odsReception" AutoGenerateRows="false" GridLines="None" DefaultMode="Edit">
  <Fields>  
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Supplier">
       <ItemTemplate>
         <myctls:DropDown runat="server" ID="ctlSupplier" Width="255" Value='<%#Bind("supplier_id") %>' />                                                                                                                    
       </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>

     [... bunch of fields ...]
   </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>

<asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="odsReception" DeleteMethod="Delete" 
        InsertMethod="Insert" SelectMethod="Select" 
        TypeName="DataAccess.Reception" 
        UpdateMethod="Update">

    <SelectParameters>
       [... Bunch of parameters ...]
    </SelectParameters>

    [... Parameters for other methods ...]
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Protected Sub DetailsView1_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DetailsView1.DataBound

            Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(DetailsView1.DataItem,DataRowView)
            Dim supplierId As String = CType(drv("supplier_id"),String)
            Dim ctrl As MyUCControl = CType(DetailsView1.FindControl("ctlSupplier"),MyUCControl)
            If (Not (ctrl) Is Nothing) Then
                ctrl.Value = supplierId
            End If

    End Sub
```

'Needs

```
Imports System.Data
```

Comment: Well... I know I can use CodeBehind for databinding, but i was looking for a solution to use databinding from the aspx file.

Comment: Your code should also work. May be something else an issue. Can you share your DetailsView code as well.

Comment: Finally, it turned out that I had a databinding conflict between code in my control and my detailsview. Once I corrected the error, my databinding code started working.